# MySQL is skipping first result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this piece of code and somehow it will always skip the first result and I have no idea why because I am using the same kind of while loop somewhere else in my code and the problem doesn't happen. If I run the MYSQL query alone without the loop I get all the results but the code below will always skip the first row. It would be great if someone could give me some advice or maybe restructure the query?

Thank you

EDIT ** added if statements

```
    ($stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT agdet.ADITEM, agdet.ADSTAT, products.IFDESC, products.ISTAT
                           FROM agdet
                           LEFT JOIN products on agdet.ADITEM = products.ITEMNO
                           LEFT JOIN aghdr    on agdet.AHNUM  = aghdr.AHNUM
                           WHERE agdet.AHCUST =? 
                             AND products.ICODE1 !=? 
                             AND aghdr.AHSTAT !=? 
                           ORDER BY agdet.ADITEM ASC 
                           LIMIT 0, 3000'))
        || fail('MySQL prepare', $db->error);
    $stmt->bind_param('iss', $agreement,$ICODE1,$AHSTAT)
        || fail('MySQL bind_param', $db->error);
    $stmt->execute()
        || fail('MySQL execute', $db->error);
    $stmt->bind_result($ADITEM,$ADSTAT,$IFDESC,$ISTAT)
        || fail('MySQL bind_result', $db->error);

    while($stmt->fetch()){



             $IFDESC = trim($IFDESC); 
             $ADITEM = trim($ADITEM); 


             if ($IFDESC == 'TAXABLE'  ){ $ADITEM = 'hidden';}
             if ($IFDESC == 'XXXX'  ){ $ADITEM = 'hidden';}
             if ($IFDESC ==''){ $IFDESC = 'Aucune description trouvée';}

             $ITEM_ID = ltrim($ADITEM, '0'); 


            if ($ISTAT =='S' OR $ADSTAT =='S'){

printf ("<p>$ADITEM</p><p>ADSTAT</p><p>$IFDESC</p><p>$ISTAT</p>");

        }
            else {

printf ("<p>$ADITEM</p><p>ADSTAT</p><p>$IFDESC</p><p>$ISTAT</p>");

    }
   }
```

Comment: Is this your actual code or psuedocode?  Nothing looks like it would cause your issue.

Comment: You should do a `var_dump()` of the variables, perhaps they are breaking the html.

Comment: This is my code just the printf as more stuff to it...some if statements that checks if the product is suspended or not

Comment: A common problem is advancing the results pointer doing validity checking and not resetting it when displaying results. The suggestion that we're not seeing some IF checks in the actual code has me leaning . . .

Comment: Ok I did a var_dump of $ADITEM without doing any IF statement and I get 12 results out of 12. string(8) "96530 " string(8) "96533 " string(8) "96534 " string(8) "96535 " string(8) "96542 " string(8) "96543 " string(8) "96740 " string(8) "96741 " string(8) "96790 " string(8) "96791 " string(8) "96792 " string(8) "96822 "

Comment: I think you may need to show what `fail()` is doing

Comment: I did comment out fail() and it was still skipping the first result. I believe the problem is related with my IF statements

Comment: Okay I added the IF statements to my OP

Answer (score 0):

Okay after more testing, my IF statements had nothing to do with this problem, it was related to printf() because if I use print_r() I will get the full result set but somehow printf() will skip the first result.

Sadly I have no idea why it is doing this, I will keep reading the doc.

Thank you!